# matlab: merging cell-arrays, converting to time series

Tags: matlab, cell-array

i'm fiddling with matlab (no toolboxes added) and am trying to understand how to create x-minute bars from a trade database.

accessing the data from SQL server, i get a cell array, Buy_Data:

```
    Attributes: []
          Data: {619134x2 cell}
DatabaseObject: [1x1 database]
      RowLimit: 0
      SQLQuery: [1x210 char]
       Message: []
          Type: 'Database Cursor Object'
     ResultSet: [1x1 com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet]
        Cursor: [1x1 com.mathworks.toolbox.database.sqlExec]
     Statement: [1x1 com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement]
         Fetch: [1x1 com.mathworks.toolbox.database.fetchTheData]
```

now, the content looks something like:

```
'2012-08-28 16:48:56.0'    [24800]
'2012-08-28 16:48:56.0'    [24800]
'2012-08-28 16:49:14.0'    [24800]
'2012-08-28 16:49:14.0'    [24800]
'2012-08-28 16:49:21.0'    [24799]
'2012-08-28 16:49:51.0'    [24800]
'2012-08-28 16:49:51.0'    [24800]
'2012-08-28 16:49:55.0'    [24800]
'2012-08-28 16:49:55.0'    [24800]
'2012-08-28 16:49:56.0'    [24800]
'2012-08-28 16:49:56.0'    [24800]
'2012-08-28 16:49:56.0'    [24800]
'2012-08-28 16:49:56.0'    [24800]
'2012-08-28 16:49:56.0'    [24800]
'2012-08-28 17:00:12.0'    [24839]
```

how do i go about combining 2 of these cell-arrays into a x-minute time series?

Comment: So, you want to convert ticks into candlesticks of arbitrary period?

Comment: yes, realising now that it is as straight forward as that.

Comment: How come there's so many double entries?

Comment: timestamped trades, could be multiple intra-second trades

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, combining the cell arrays is as simple as

```
new_Data = [Buy_data.Data; Buy_data2.Data]
```

where obviously, `Buy_data` and `Buy_data2` are your two different structures.

Combining these into an x-minute candlestick format can be done like this:

```
% example data
new_cell = {
    '2012-08-28 16:48:56.0'    [24800]
    '2012-08-28 16:48:56.0'    [24800]
    '2012-08-28 16:49:14.0'    [24800]
    '2012-08-28 16:49:14.0'    [24800]
    '2012-08-28 16:49:21.0'    [24799]
    '2012-08-28 16:49:51.0'    [24800]
    '2012-08-28 16:49:51.0'    [24800]
    '2012-08-28 16:49:55.0'    [24800]
    '2012-08-28 16:49:55.0'    [24800]
    '2012-08-28 16:49:56.0'    [24800]
    '2012-08-28 16:49:56.0'    [24800]
    '2012-08-28 16:49:56.0'    [24800]
    '2012-08-28 16:49:56.0'    [24800]
    '2012-08-28 16:49:56.0'    [24800]
    '2012-08-28 17:00:12.0'    [24839]
    };

% your period (in minutes)
x = 1; 



% convert dates to numbers and make sure dates are sorted
[dateNums, sortInds] = sort(datenum(new_cell(:,1)));
prices = [new_cell{:,2}].';
prices = prices(sortInds);

% find minimum date, maximum date
minDate = min(dateNums);
maxDate = max(dateNums);

% group data into bins
x = x/24/60;
numBins = ceil( (maxDate-minDate)/x );
[N,X] = hist(dateNums,numBins);

% create candlesticks
inds          = [1 cumsum(N)];
candles.min   = zeros(numBins,1);
candles.max   = zeros(numBins,1);
candles.open  = zeros(numBins,1);
candles.close = zeros(numBins,1);
candles.dates = cell(numBins,1);
for ii = 1:numBins

    % we already know the dates
    candles.dates{ii} = datestr(X(ii));

    % continue only if there's data    
    if N(ii)
        % extract the prices
        subSet = prices(inds(ii):inds(ii+1));
        % find max, min, open, close
        candles.open(ii)  = subSet(1);
        candles.close(ii) = subSet(end);
        candles.max(ii)   = max(subSet);
        candles.min(ii)   = min(subSet);        
    end    

end
```

Note that you need to do some tweaking, as these would be pretty unrepresentable candlesticks :) Anyway, it should be enough to get you started.